# Prove that the area of a Pythagoras triple is divisible by 2, 3 and then 6

Tags: pythagorean-triples

Prove that the area of a Pythagoras triple is divisible by 2, 3 and then 6. 
I know that in the Pythagoras triple (x,y,z) area is equal to 1/2(xy). But I am unsure how to prove this statement.

Comment: This question is a little different, mine is looking at the are of the triple, where that is looking at the individual sides.

Comment: The differences from the other question are that you need one of your sides to be divisible by $4$ and that you are not allowed to consider divisibility of the hypotenuse.

Comment: Yes, it looks different at first glance, but if one side is divisible by $3$, then the area is as well. You do have to show that one of the sides must be divisible by $4$.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Euclid's formula for Pythagorean triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple).  Every Pythagorean triangle is a multiple of a primitive triangle, were the legs have no common factor.  The primitive triangles have $a=m^2-n^2, b=2mn, c=m^2+n^2$ with $m,n$ coprime and of opposite parity.  As they are of opposite parity one is even, so $b$ is a multiple of $4$ and the area is even.  If neither $m$ nor $n$ is a multiple of $3$ then $a$ is, if one is a multiple of $3$ then $b$ is.  Either way the area is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: Since 6 is a multiple of 3, does that prove that case as well?

Comment: Once you prove both 2 and 3 you have 6 as well.  You need both.